# Python regex replace and use match

Tags: python, python-re

I have a text, I want to replace all the attachment:ATT000xx files to another link /dwl/attachment/ATT000xx

```
regex = "attachment:ATT\d+"
txt = "<img src=\"attachment:ATT00001\""

x = re.sub("attachment:ATT\d+", "/dwl/attachment/", txt)
```

How can I find last numbers(00001/00002) and put the end of line

in nodejs it will be

```
.replace(/attachment:([a-f0-9]+)\/(ATT\d+)/g, (str, mid, aid) =>
```

aid is what I looking for for nodejs

Comment: if file attachment:ATT00001 then /dwl/attachment/ATT00001

Answer (score 2):

Use a capture group for the ATT + number term:

```py
txt = "<img src=\"attachment:ATT00001\">"
output = re.sub(r'attachment:(ATT\d+)', r'/dwl/attachment/\1', txt)
print(output)  # <img src="/dwl/attachment/ATT00001">
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you only need to match the part you wish to replace. For this you can use a positive lookahead:

```
regex = "attachment:ATT(?=\d+)"
txt = "<img src=\"attachment:ATT00001\""

x = re.sub(regex, "/dwl/attachment/", txt)
print(x)
```

This would match any `attachment:ATT` that is followed by one or more digits, but **won't** match the digits.